# How to fix os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.relpath('my_file')) not returning the path to 'my_file'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.path

I have the following working directory: `/Users/jordan/Coding/Employer/code_base`, and the file I want to get the absolute path for is located at `/Users/jordan/Coding/Employer/code_base/framework/GTC/tests/day_document.json`.
I have tests in the file `/Users/jordan/Coding/Employer/code_base/framework/GTC/tests/test.py`.

Currently when I use `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.relpath('day_document.json')` I'm getting `/Users/jordan/Coding/Employer/code_base/day_document.json`. I want to get the correct filepath to `day_document.json` so that tests can work properly in CI. The code is currently running in the test file, located at `/Users/jordan/Coding/Employer/code_base/framework/GTC/tests/test.py`.

I've already tried `os.path.relpath('day_document.json')` and `os.path.abspath('day_document.json')` in `os.join`, and both return `/Users/jordan/Coding/Employer/code_base/day_document.json`. I've also done a ton of googling, but can't seem to find anything where people are getting the correct answer. When I use `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'framework/GTC/tests/day_document.json')`, I get the correct behavior, but I don't want to hardcode file paths.

This works:

```
day_document_file_location = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'framework/GTC/tests/day_document.json')
with open(day_document_file_location, 'r') as day_doc_json:
    day_doc_endpoint._content = day_doc_json.read()
```

But I don't understand why this doesn't:

```
day_document_file_location = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.relpath('day_document.json'))
with open(day_document_file_location, 'r') as day_doc_json:
    day_doc_endpoint._content = day_doc_json.read()
```

I have to mention, that the latter code works when I run it from the file location, but not from the working directory.

I want to find a way to not hard code a file path, and be able to get `/Users/jordan/Coding/Employer/code_base/framework/GTC/tests/day_document.json` from the working directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [[Python 3.Docs]: os.path.**relpath**(*path, start=os.curdir*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) (**emphasis** is mine):

> ... This is a path computation: the **filesystem is not accessed to confirm the existence** or nature of *path* or *start*.

If you don't want to hardcode *framework/GTC/tests/day_document.json* (the intermediary dirs), you need to search for the file. One way would be to use [[Python 3.Docs]: glob.**iglob**(*pathname, *, recursive=False*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.iglob):

```py
document_name = "day_document.json"
document_path = ""
for p in glob.iglob(os.path.join("**", document_name), recursive=True):
    document_path = os.path.abspath(p)
    break
if not document_path:
    # Handle file not being present, e.g.:
    raise FileNotFoundError(document_name)
```

Needless to say that if you have more than one file with that name in the dir tree, the 1<sup>st</sup> one will be returned (and there's no guarantee that it will be the one you're expecting).

Comment: You are incredible. Thank You!